# List comprehension for series of deltas

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How would you write a list comprehension in python to generate a series of `n-1` deltas between `n` items in an ordered list?

Example:

```
L = [5,9,2,1,7]
RES = [5-9,9-2,2-1,1-7] = [4,7,1,6] # absolute values
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RES = [abs(L[i]-L[i+1]) for i in range(len(L)-1)]
```

Answer (score 4):

The [recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) section of the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) includes source code for a function called pairwise that you can use for this purpose:

```
from itertools import *

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    b.next()
    return izip(a, b)
```

You can copy and paste this into your file. With this function defined it is quite simple to do what you want:

```
l = [5, 9, 2, 1, 7]
print [abs(a-b) for a,b in pairwise(l)]
```

Result

```
[4, 7, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out:

```
[abs(x-y) for x,y in zip(L[:-1], L[1:])]
```

Comment: For large lists you might want to use itertools.izip instead of zip. http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip

Comment: I don't like the unnecessary duplication of the original list.